# In Angular 5 how to I avoid some components/pages from having the NavMenuComponent?

Tags: angular, typescript

For example, using the template generated in visual studio 2017 for the Angular app, when I create a new component, and associated path in RouterModule, whenever I navigate to that path, the view will contain the NavMenuComponent. 
I know of a workaround to HIDE the nav, but I don't have the NavMenuComponent to be initialized at all. how can I accomplish this?

Again, I know I can HIDE the nav, but I don't want NavMenuComponent to be initialized in the lifecycle at all, nor any of the NavMenuComponent components itself. Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple layout components.

For example a basic layout component would look like this:

```
<nav></nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer></footer>
```

Call this NavLayoutComponent. And create another called LayoutComponent without the nav like this:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer></footer>
```

Then in your routes define which layout component to use:

```
{
  path: 'help', component: NavLayoutComponent,
  children: [
    {path: 'help', component: HelpComponent}
  ]
}
```

Here, all children have a navbar.

```
{
  path: 'login', component: LayoutComponent,
  children: [
    {path: '', component: LoginComponent}
  ]
}
```

Here, all children have no navbar.

Your app.component.html would simply have:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This would insert the appropriate layout component.

Alternatively and much simpler, just use one layout component and use *ngIf

```
<nav *ngIf="this.router.url IS IN MY LIST OF ALLOWED URLS"></nav>
```

Note that *ngIf does prevent initialisation if it is false.

Comment: so what would the full code be within 'RouterModule.forRoot([..]) in the first case?

Comment: can you update the answer with that code snippet forRoot?

Comment: Also, I have just tried using the second approach, but the component NavMenuComponent is still in fact being initialized. So that doesnt appear to work entirely. The second aproach does hide the HTML, but it doesnt prevent initialization..

Comment: also, if approach number 1 was taken, what would be contained within the app.component.html then? nothing?

Comment: also, the approach number 1 would require navigion to path /help/help, which doesnt make sense right?